Call animation via Dropdown's value change
----------------------EDIT 01/06/2024--------------------
Made changes according to @ITL suggestion but still in no avail.
According to DebugLog only the dropdown value was changed but animator value is not changed at all.
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;


public class AnimINTviaDropdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator; // Reference to the Animator component
    public int animIndex; // Index of the integer parameter in the Animator
    private TMP_Dropdown dropdown; // Reference to the TMP_Dropdown component

    private void Start()
    {
        dropdown = GetComponent<TMP_Dropdown>(); // Get the reference to the TMP_Dropdown component
        dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnDropdownValueChanged); // Subscribe to the value changed event
    }

    private void OnDropdownValueChanged(int selectedValue)
    {
       // Set the integer parameter value in the Animator
       animator.SetInteger(animIndex, selectedValue);
    }

}

--------- (EDIT END) below is Original Post -----------
Trying to call animation via Dropdown's value change, in no avail.
Current code and setting as below:
public class MaPoseListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Dropdown dropdown;

    public Animator ma_Animator;

    public void setAnimINT()
    {   
        int pickedEntryIndex = dropdown.value;
        ma_Animator.SetInteger("AnimMaInt", pickedEntryIndex);
    }
}


and inspector setting as below:
Inspector setting

You need to subscribe to it using onValueChanged:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TMP_Dropdown.html
You can read about the observer pattern here: https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html

Much thanks for your comment. Tried to add in the onValueChanged but in no avail. I'm wondering is there any noob mistake I've made in below code...
{
    public TMP_Dropdown dropdown;

    public Animator ma_Animator;public void setAnimINT()
    {   
        int pickedEntryIndex = dropdown.value;
        ma_Animator.SetInteger("AnimMaInt", pickedEntryIndex);
    }

    public TMP_Dropdown.DropdownEvent onValueChanged { get; set; }```

Sorry for code mess above... I wonder how to post code properly in comment section

You have to subscribe to it in Start or Awake
